# Can I group Data by Mutual Fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query, graph-query

Hi I'm currently trying to create a query to group customers together.

I'm currently wanting to group by "Phone Number", "Email" and maybe some other fields in the future.

My problem is that I may want to group rows which aren't directly linked but have mutual rows.

For example, in this diagram we can see that Customer 2 and Customer 5 are in no way related at all, however they both share connections with Customer 1 which would then allow them to group together.

Venn Diagram Describing my ideal Data Set
[image: Venn Diagram Describing my ideal Data Set]

Here is another View:
CustomerId    | FullName         | PhoneNumber        | Email
--|--|--|---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            | Bill Smith       | 01612345678        | BillS@SqlTeam.com
2              | Kelly Smith      | 01612345678        | KellyS@SqlTeam.com
3              | Kevin Roach      | 07111111111        | KevinR@Example.com
4              | Chris Ronald     | 07222222222        | ChrisR@Blog.co.uk
5              | Bill Smith       | 07987654321        | BillS@SqlTeam.com

We can see that Customer 2 is connected to Customer 1 through a mutual Phone Number, and Customer 5 is connected to 1 through a mutual Email Address. However Customer 2 and Customer 5 share no information which would've originally grouped them.

My reasoning for needing this functionality is that one person / household could have multiple customer accounts all with differing information therefore I am trying to group them up as best as I can with as much mutual information as possible.

I have already tried to use `DENSE_RANK()` and `GROUP BY`, however these seem the additionally partition the groups when adding more than 1 column, I want a group to be created solely on the fact that a data field matches another.

Comment: you have omitted to show your expectected results.

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of recursive algorithm, or possibly a graph table.

Comment: Please read [mre] and add the results you'd like from your example data.

Answer (score 0):

I've adopted the excellent answer from [How can I combine Group Identifiers into Single Group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272634/how-can-i-combine-group-identifiers-into-single-group/76273429#76273429) by GMB to your issue:

```sql
SELECT  *
INTO    #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'Bill Smith', N'01612345678', N'BillS@SqlTeam.com', NULL)
    ,   (2, N'Kelly Smith', N'01612345678', N'KellyS@SqlTeam.com', NULL)
    ,   (3, N'Kevin Roach', N'07111111111', N'KevinR@Example.com', '12345')
    ,   (4, N'Chris Ronald', N'07222222222', N'ChrisR@Blog.co.uk', NULL)
    ,   (5, N'Bill Smith', N'07987654321', N'BillS@SqlTeam.com', NULL)
    ,   (6, N'Gill Smith', N'07987654322', NULL, 12345)
    ,   (7, N'Gill McGill', N'07987654322', NULL, NULL)
    ,   (8, N'Gillian Smith', NULL, NULL, 12345)
    ,   (9, N'Smith W', NULL, 'KellyS@SqlTeam.comx', 12345)
) t (CustomerId,FullName,PhoneNumber,Email, Fax)

;WITH edges AS (
    SELECT  d.customerid, d2.customerid AS custIdTo
    FROM    #data d
    INNER JOIN #data d2
        ON  (
            d2.PhoneNumber = d.PhoneNumber
        OR  d2.email = d.email
        OR  d2.fax = d.fax
        )
        --AND   d2.customerid <> d.customerid -- remove unmatched customers by uncommenting this row
    ) 
, rec AS (
    SELECT  customerid, custidto, cast(concat(customerid, ',', custidto) AS nvarchar(max)) AS path
    FROM    edges
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  c.customerid, e.custidto, concat(path, ',', e.custidto)
    FROM    rec c
    INNER JOIN edges e
        ON  e.customerid = c.custidto
    WHERE   ',' + path + ',' NOT LIKE '%,' + cast(e.custidto AS nvarchar(max)) + ',%'
    
    )
SELECT  customerid, CAST(MIN(x.value) AS INT) AS baseCustomer
FROM    rec 
CROSS apply string_split(path, ',') x
GROUP BY customerid
option(maxrecursion 0);
```

As a sample, i've added a fax field, and the customers are matched by either phone, email or fax.

It's a bit complicated to explain how it works.

First i create some sample data and put it into #data table.

Then we do two CTEs:

- edges contains all the matches between customers.
- a recursing cte called rec works by first selecting all the matches. Then for each match, it keeps the original customerid, and then checks which other matches exist between the *customerIdTo* and its own matches.
- the cte will build a thing called path, which is the "road" it took from each match, by doing a concat between custIdFrom, "," and custIdTo.

For example if we have following edge data:

```
  from to
  1  2
  2  3
  3  1
```

it will take 1 => 2, and then look for 2's match in the edge data, and found 2 => 3. Then it will look for 3's matches and find 3 => 1.

So for customer 1, it will create three rows, 1 => 2, 1 => 3, 3 => 1, but then it will check so it doesn't loop back to same row already done, so 3 => 1 will be discarded because 1 it was already in 1 => 2 path.

This check is performed here: `WHERE  ',' + path + ',' NOT LIKE '%,' + cast(e.custidto AS nvarchar(max))`

If we don't do this check, the loop will continue forever which isn't great.

Finally, we have a lot of rows with customer and the path to each node. To get the matching node, we do a string_split and get the minimum "custIdTo" value for each customerId

EDIT: The performance of these things ain't great because of the sheer amount of potential loops and joins. An alternative could be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75560065/13061224 which is a bit more trivial but means loops