Recursive CTE - Get all relatives of all relatives
I have data with IDs that I need to identify as being related. I'm having trouble identifying relatives-of-relatives (and relatives-of-relatives-of-relatives and so on...).
*Part of the issue is that the data really isn't hierarchical. They are being identified as related based on various fields matching (drivers license #, ssn, etc). I laid the data out so that the Parent is always the lower ID # so that we wouldn't encounter any infinite loops in the recursion.
Sample data:
drop table if exists #AllSimilarMinParent 
create table #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId bigint, ChildId bigint)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (10, 20)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (20, 30)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (30, 40)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (40, 50)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (39, 40)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (39, 51)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (49, 51)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (49, 61)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (59, 61)
insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (59, 71)


I am using a recursive CTE to get the hierarchy for each ID:
    WITH RelationHierarchy as (
    SELECT  ChildId,  ParentId
    FROM #AllSimilarMinParent MP
)
, RCTE AS
(
    --recursive CTE to generate hierarchy
    SELECT  ParentId, ChildId, 1 AS Lvl FROM RelationHierarchy 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT rh.ParentId, rc.ChildId, Lvl+1 AS Lvl 
    FROM RelationHierarchy rh
        INNER JOIN RCTE rc ON rh.ChildId = rc.ParentId
)
select F0.ParentId, F0.ChildId, F0.Lvl FROM RCTE F0 ORDER BY ChildId, ParentId

Which returns the following:



ParentId
ChildId
Lvl




10
20
1


10
30
2


20
30
1


10
40
3


20
40
2


30
40
1


39
40
1


10
50
4


20
50
3


30
50
2


39
50
2


40
50
1


39
51
1


49
51
1


49
61
1


59
61
1


59
71
1



I also tried joining back to the CTE to get all relatives of relatives:
        select F0.ParentId, F0.ChildId, F0.Lvl FROM RCTE F0
        UNION
        select F1.ChildId, F2.ChildId, -1 FROM RCTE F1 JOIN RCTE F2 ON F1.ParentId = F2.ParentId AND F1.ChildId <> F2.ChildId
        UNION
        select F2.ParentId, F1.ParentId, -2 FROM RCTE F1 JOIN RCTE F2 ON F1.ChildId = F2.ChildId AND F1.ParentId <> F2.ParentId


..and that helped to a degree, but I'm still not getting every relation I'm looking for. For example, I can not get 10 being related to 71. The way this particular data is related, it seems I would have to go up (to parent) and down (to child) multiple times to go from :
71 up to 59
59 down to 61
61 up to 49
49 down to 51
51 up to 39
39 down to 40
40 up to 30
30 up to 20
20 up to 10
I thought about using the results of the first recursive CTE in another recursive CTE, but the fact that it has to go both up AND down randomly (i.e. up THEN down, not consistently one direction or the other) has me stumped.
Any ideas how I can definitively return every permutation of related records? Every ID in this particular data set should be related to every other ID.
Below is the desired output, showing every ID related to every other



ParentId
ChildId




10
20


10
30


10
39


10
40


10
49


10
50


10
51


10
59


10
61


10
71


20
30


20
39


20
40


20
49


20
50


20
51


20
59


20
61


20
71


30
39


30
40


30
49


30
50


30
51


30
59


30
61


30
71


39
40


39
49


39
50


39
51


39
59


39
61


39
71


40
49


40
50


40
51


40
59


40
61


40
71


49
50


49
51


49
59


49
61


49
71


50
51


50
59


50
61


50
71


51
59


51
61


51
71


59
61


59
71


61
71



**EDIT - This question is closed as duplicate of these:
How to find all connected subgraphs of an undirected graph
How can I combine Group Identifiers into Single Group?
While they do show a method to get the desired result, their performance is unacceptably slow. See my answer below.
*EDIT2 - Instead of a recursive CTE I ended up using a WHILE loop to go through relatives' relatives until no more exist. Very loosely based on this question . I'm posting my final solution here because the question was closed. if it gets reopened I will post as an answer:
    --initial values
    drop table if exists #AllRelations 
    create table #AllRelations (ParentId bigint, ChildId bigint)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (10, 20)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (20, 30)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (30, 40)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (40, 50)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (39, 40)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (39, 51)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (49, 51)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (49, 61)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (59, 61)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (59, 71)
    insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (159, 171) --these should be a second group
    --insert into #AllRelations (ParentId, ChildId) values (39, 171) --this would make it all 1 group again

    --create table for all extended matches
    drop table if exists #ExtendedMatches
    create table #ExtendedMatches (ParentId BIGINT, ChildId BIGINT)

    declare @RecordsAdded bigint = 0

    --add our initial matches
    INSERT INTO #ExtendedMatches(ParentId, ChildId) 
    select ParentId, ChildId 
    FROM #AllRelations

    set @RecordsAdded = @@ROWCOUNT

    WHILE @RecordsAdded > 0
    BEGIN
        --create temp table with all combinations of relatives' relatives
        drop table if exists #FamilyTree
        ; with Q as (
            select r1.ParentId, r1.ChildId, r2.ParentId as FoundParentId, r2.ChildId as FoundChildId
            FROM #ExtendedMatches r1
                join #ExtendedMatches r2 on r2.ParentId = r1.ChildId 
                    AND r2.ChildId <> r1.ParentId --to ensure it's not an identical record
            UNION 
            select r1.ParentId, r1.ChildId, r2.ParentId, r2.ChildId
            FROM #ExtendedMatches r1
                join #ExtendedMatches r2 on r2.ChildId = r1.ParentId 
                    AND r2.ParentId <> r1.ChildId --to ensure it's not an identical record
            UNION 
            select r1.ParentId, r1.ChildId, r2.ParentId, r2.ChildId
            FROM #ExtendedMatches r1
                join #ExtendedMatches r2 on r2.ChildId = r1.ChildId 
                    AND r2.ParentId <> r1.ParentId --to ensure it's not an identical record
            UNION 
            select r1.ParentId, r1.ChildId, r2.ParentId, r2.ChildId
            FROM #ExtendedMatches r1
                join #ExtendedMatches r2 on r2.ParentId = r1.ParentId 
                    AND r2.ChildId <> r1.ChildId --to ensure it's not an identical record
        )
        select * 
        INTO #FamilyTree
        FROM Q

        --add new matches to #ExtendedMatches table
        INSERT INTO #ExtendedMatches (ParentId, ChildId)
        SELECT ParentId, ChildId
        FROM (
            --get all combinations, using the lower number as the ParentId and higher number as ChildId
            select ParentId = CASE WHEN ParentId < ChildId THEN ParentId ELSE ChildId END, ChildId = CASE WHEN ParentId < ChildId THEN ChildId ELSE ParentId END FROM #FamilyTree WHERE ParentId <>  ChildId UNION
            select ParentId = CASE WHEN ParentId < FoundParentId THEN ParentId ELSE FoundParentId END, ChildId = CASE WHEN ParentId < FoundParentId THEN FoundParentId ELSE ParentId END FROM #FamilyTree WHERE ParentId <> FoundParentId UNION
            select ParentId = CASE WHEN ParentId < FoundChildId THEN ParentId ELSE FoundChildId END, ChildId = CASE WHEN ParentId < FoundChildId THEN FoundChildId ELSE ParentId END FROM #FamilyTree WHERE ParentId <> FoundChildId UNION
            select ParentId = CASE WHEN ChildId < FoundParentId THEN ChildId ELSE FoundParentId END, ChildId = CASE WHEN ChildId < FoundParentId THEN FoundParentId ELSE ChildId END FROM #FamilyTree WHERE ChildId <>  FoundParentId UNION
            select ParentId = CASE WHEN ChildId < FoundChildId THEN ChildId ELSE FoundChildId END, ChildId = CASE WHEN ChildId < FoundChildId THEN FoundChildId ELSE ChildId END FROM #FamilyTree WHERE ChildId <>  FoundChildId UNION
            select ParentId = CASE WHEN FoundParentId < FoundChildId THEN FoundParentId ELSE FoundChildId END, ChildId = CASE WHEN FoundParentId < FoundChildId THEN FoundChildId ELSE FoundParentId END FROM #FamilyTree WHERE FoundParentId <>  FoundChildId
        ) Q
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from #FamilyTree f2 where f2.ParentId = q.parentid and f2.ChildId = q.childid)

        set @RecordsAdded = @@ROWCOUNT
    END--keep adding until no new relatives are found

    --everyone is related to everyone they should be:
    select * FROM #ExtendedMatches 

    --get distinct list of all IDs
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AllIds
    SELECT distinct Id
    INTO #AllIds
    FROM (
        select distinct ParentId as Id FROM #ExtendedMatches  UNION 
        SELECT distinct ChildId as Id FROM #ExtendedMatches 
    ) Q

    --get the minimum parent for each ID. 
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #IdParents
    select A.Id
        , MinParentId = ISNULL((select min(ParentId) FROM #ExtendedMatches E WHERE E.ChildId = A.Id), A.Id) --if none found, use the ID as its own parent
    INTO #IdParents
    FROM #AllIds A

    --assign group numbers to each top-level parent
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AllParents
    SELECT MinParentId, GroupNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MinParentId)
    INTO #AllParents
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MinParentId FROM #IdParents) q

    --results
    select I.Id, I.MinParentId, A.GroupNumber 
    FROM #IdParents I
        JOIN #AllParents A ON A.MinParentId = I.MinParentId
        


The results are as expected:



Id
MinParentId
GroupNumber




10
10
1


20
10
1


30
10
1


39
10
1


40
10
1


49
10
1


50
10
1


51
10
1


59
10
1


61
10
1


71
10
1


159
159
2


171
159
2




This feels like a task better suitable for a graph database.

You have shown the results that you currently get and it is clear that this differs from the result you expect. Could you also show what exactly you would expect?

@LajosArpad question updated to show desired output.

@TN This appears to be similar to the one posted by siggemannen above. In both cases performance becomes an issue pretty quickly (see my less-than-ideal answer below, but long story short it appears the recursive CTE method is just not going to work due to performance).

@EricG - I examined the answers in the linked "duplicate" questions and agree that there are  performance issues. I particular, some of the algorithms appeared to have complexity approaching N^4 or even N^2 * N! for certain data. After a deep dive I added a new answer here that shows improved performance in many scenarios - particularly those with graphs having redundant paths and loops. I suggest that you take a look.

I was able to adapt the answer that siggemannen posted above:
how-can-i-combine-group-identifiers-into-single-group
..and it did give the expected results. However, the performance is just not going to work. For the 11 records in my sample data, it took 11 seconds. I added 11 more records that were not related to my initial 11 records in any way, and the query took over a minute. When I added 1 more record that related one record from the first set, to one record in the second set (meaning all 22 IDs are now related to each other in some way), the query has been running for over a half hour. In my real world application, I am expecting to have in the tens-of-thousands of records to deal with.
The (working but painfully slow) solution:
--create relations
    drop table if exists #AllSimilarMinParent 
    create table #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId bigint, ChildId bigint)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (10, 20)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (20, 30)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (30, 40)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (40, 50)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (39, 40)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (39, 51)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (49, 51)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (49, 61)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (59, 61)
    insert into #AllSimilarMinParent (ParentId, ChildId) values (59, 71)

--build recursive CTE and put results into temp table
    drop table if exists #RCTE
    ;
    WITH RelationHierarchy as (
        SELECT  ChildId,  ParentId
        FROM #AllSimilarMinParent MP
    )
    , RCTE AS
    (
        --recursive CTE to generate hierarchy
        SELECT  ParentId, ChildId, 1 AS Lvl FROM RelationHierarchy 

        UNION ALL

        SELECT rh.ParentId, rc.ChildId, Lvl+1 AS Lvl 
        FROM RelationHierarchy rh
            INNER JOIN RCTE rc ON rh.ChildId = rc.ParentId
    )
        select F0.ParentId, F0.ChildId, F0.Lvl 
        INTO #RCTE 
        FROM RCTE F0
        select * FROM #RCTE

--create all combinations (both directions)
    drop table if exists #mytable2
    create table #mytable2 (id int, groupid int)
    insert into #mytable2 (id, groupid) 
    select ParentId, ChildId FROM #RCTE 
    UNION
    select ChildId, ParentId FROM #RCTE 
    UNION
    select ParentId, ParentId FROM #RCTE --also needed every ID to belog to itself as a group
    UNION
    select ChildId, ChildId FROM #RCTE  --also needed every ID to belog to itself as a group


--suggested solution adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272634/how-can-i-combine-group-identifiers-into-single-group?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top
    ;with 
        uniquenodes as (select distinct id from #mytable2)
        , nodes as (
            select t.id, v.grp
            from uniquenodes t
            cross apply ( select groupid from #mytable2 t1 where t1.id = t.id ) v(grp)
        )
        ,
        edges as (
            select distinct n1.id as id1, n2.id as id2
            from nodes n1
            inner join nodes n2 on n1.grp = n2.grp
        )
        ,
        rec as (
            select id1, id2, cast(id1 as nvarchar(max)) as visited from edges
            union all
            select r.id1, e.id2, concat(r.visited, ',', e.id2)
            from rec r
            inner join edges e on e.id1 = r.id2
            where concat(',', r.visited, ',') not like concat('%,', e.id2, ',%')
        )
        ,
        fin as (
            select id1, min(value) min_id
            from rec r
            cross apply string_split(r.visited, ',')
            group by id1
        )
    select id1 as id, dense_rank() over(order by min_id) grp
    from fin f


it puts all 11 ID's in group 1, which does meet my needs. Initial testing shows that manipulating the IDs gives expected results (creates a second group if I orphan IDs or add new IDs only related to each other), but I haven't tested too much further due to the performance.

There's a looped version of this method which is faster. It's either in the duplicate comments or somewhere else :)

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559657/creating-a-single-id-for-any-combination-of-matches-between-three-different-iden/75560065#75560065

@siggemannen I was able to build something similar to the answer [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559657/creating-a-single-id-for-any-combination-of-matches-between-three-different-iden/75560065#75560065) . I will post it in the original question because the question ended up getting closed as a duplicate and I can no longer post new answers. see code after **EDIT2)

I voted to reopen it, have another answer myself :)
