# Need help on SQL query, to merge comma separated rows when there is a match

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help on framing SQL query (MS SQL Server)
Want to merge Keys. Here Code-ABC to be merged for all matching values of each column.

```
Code    Keys
ABC 100,200
ABC 200,300
ABC 100,500
XYZ 100,201
ABC 500,600
ABC 700,800
```

Output:

```
Code    Keys
ABC 100,200,300,500,600
XYZ 100,201
ABC 700,800
```

I have tried CTE & STRRING_AGG but was able to merge Keys for the distinct Code only.
But my result, should only merge Keys only if one key value matches with any other other and then this value with any other column

Comment: Sounds like you need a recursive CTE to get all connected nodes. Storing them as comma separated strings is only making this harder, it should be two separate columns (or separate rows if the number is dynamic). Does each row have a unique `Id`?

Comment: Why not fix your design? That is the *real* solution. Taking bad data, and making is only slightly less bad still leaves you with bad data. Fix the root of the problem.

Comment: @ThomA Fixing the design won't necessarily help much. It's a graph-walking problem, and cannot be solved with a non-recursive solution.

Comment: The key values are dynamic and here I have just listed two per row to simplify. It may have any number of values for each Code. I also tried by making self join of this spitted rows using STRING_SPLIT but couldn't get exact result. And the above is just small code of a Stored Procedure where I'm trying to merge few rows.

Comment: Another solution which uses loop based logic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75559657/creating-a-single-id-for-any-combination-of-matches-between-three-different-iden/75560065#75560065 for that, you need some kind of pseudo ID